# Spider identification

Tags: spider-mites

[image]

Can someone help identify this spider. At first I thought I had, and treated for spider mites. This guy has 8 legs and builds a full web. I have yet to see an egg sack but started “treatment” at first sight.

If he’s plant friendly, I’ll leave him alone. I’ve not seen them get much bigger than the photos. My friend doesn’t have plants but I just found them on his patio, and decided to ask the community, instead of treating my plants again.

Comment: Spiders never, if I remember correctly, eat plants; they're known as beneficials. Leave this guy alone.

Comment: Too big for spider mite.

Answer (score 2):

Its hard to see from the picture but, it seems to be a household and plant spider. Those are not harmful and usually build webs to capture small bugs and such. Good plant defenders and survive very well. If you don't have issues with spiders or getting tons of them then leave em on plants. They like 7 jumping spiders https://www.prevention.com/health/g29022991/common-house-spiders/ I seen this in my house and I don't like spiders. But, in the plants I don't mind em.

Answer (score 1):

You have mealy bugs, not spiders. They make cottony webs.

Use soap and water, or alcohol, or natural spray. Often.

[**Long-Tailed Mealy Bug**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudococcus_longispinus)

[image: Long-tailed Mealy Bug]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Mealybug_PNr%C2%B00445.jpg

Comment: Its possible, but its hard to tell without a better photo.